# Change Card View Elevation Color

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

How can I change the color of the card view elevation?

Or make it softer

It gets dark when I increase the `app:cardElevation` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can change color first you can make a drawable file and paste this code in it. then in your layout inside cardview, you can assign as background file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
            android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#ddd"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: android:background="@drawable/youDrawableFile" in layout which is inside cardview

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
       app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/yourcolor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@drawable/yourDrawableFile"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001921/changing-cardview-shadow-color?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Add these 2 properties to your `CardView`

```
android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/yourShadowColor"
android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/yourShadowColor"
```