How to increase the intensity of the shadow of a View in Android
i am trying to create a selection effect in android using cardview , but i am unable to achieve the effect as expected, please help me or suggest me how it can be achieved same as below image



Shadows in Android are not on all four sides evenly. If you want to implement this glow effect, you will need to handle it yourself.

can you please suggest something how to achieve this ? or any reference ?

If you search android glow "behind" widget in major search engines, you will find resources like https://stackoverflow.com/q/51001921/115145 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45704019/115145.
